# Time Series Plot for floating values

Tags: time-series, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plotting

I have a Dataframe which looks as shown below

[image]

I am trying to make a line plot for looking at the peaks for both columns (a,b), I have gotten as far as

```
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
plt.plot(wr['a'][:100])
plt.show()
```

but the plot looks shabby,
[image]

```
wr.set_index(['Date_x'],inplace=True)
wr['a'][:100].plot()
wr['b'][:100].plot()
```

[image]

I am looking to have something like this
[image]

Any Help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
wr.reset_index().plot(x='index', y=['a', 'b'], figsize=(10,5), grid=True)
```

- The `reset_index()` will change the index back to column
- The `x = 'index'` will use the date index as the x axis
- The `y=['a','b']` will plot both columns as two time series
- `figsize` just tell the plot how big to be
- `grid=True` will add a grid on the plot

You will need to give some extra 'love' to your styling to make it look exactly as your example.